# Passando valor da variável pelo $.post

Tags: php, javascript

Estou tentando porem não sei como mandar o valor do select para a pagina pagseguro.php

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Pedido de teste</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div>
    <h1>Produto de Teste</h1>
    <p>Valor: 299,00</p>
    <button onclick="enviaPagseguro();">Comprar</button><br />
    <img src="loading.gif" id="loading" style="visibility: hidden">
</div>

<form id="comprar" action="https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/checkout/payment.html" method="post" onsubmit="PagSeguroLightbox(this); return false;">
    <input type="hidden" name="code" id="code" value="" />
    <select name="itemAmount1">
        <option value="10.00">Tentar obter 1000 Donate Points</option>
        <option value="30.00">Tentar obter 3500 Donate Points</option>
        <option value="50.00">Tentar obter 6000 Donate Points</option>
        <option value="80.00">Tentar obter 9500 Donate Points</option>
        <option value="150.00">Tentar obter 20000 Donate Points</option>
        <option value="225.00">Tentar obter 30000 Donate Points</option>
    </select>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stc.pagseguro.uol.com.br/pagseguro/api/v2/checkout/pagseguro.lightbox.js"></script>

<script>
    function enviaPagseguro(codigo){

        $.post('salvarpedido.php','',function(idPedido){

            $('#loading').css("visibility","visible");

            $.post('pagseguro.php',{idPedido: idPedido},function(data){

                $('#code').val(data);
                $('#comprar').submit();

                $('#loading').css("visibility","hidden");
            })
        })
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Alguem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode pegar o valor do `select` com o código:

```
$("select[name='itemAmount1']").val();
```

Comment: Mas como mandaria para o pagseguro.php?

Comment: Aqui {idPedido: idPedido} eu sei que passa idPedido mais como eu passo itemAmount1?

Comment: `,itemAmount1: $("select[name='itemAmount1']").val()`

Comment: $.post('pagseguro.php',{idPedido: idPedido,itemAmount1: $("select[name='itemAmount1']").val()},function(data) Pegou.

Answer (score 0):

Seu código está certo, basta adicionar a variável do post no itemAmount1.

Na página pagseguro.php:

```
$data['itemAmount1'] = $_POST['itemAmount1'];
```

O nome do parâmetro do post deve ser o mesmo nome do select.